# What does "Brennersperrzeit" mean in the context of a hot water/heating system?

Tags: translation

My heating is currently not working because the "Brennersperrzeit" is currently activated. What would the English term be for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://www.haustechnikdialog.de/Forum/t/10559/Brennersperrzeit-was-ist-das-) or [this](https://www.gutefrage.net/frage/heizkoerper-werden-nicht-warm-thermendruck-heizkoerperentlueftung-etc-stimmen-aber-was-tun). Quotation:

> Wenn die Brennersperrzeit aktiv ist, dann kann die Heizung nicht anspringen, da der Brenner gesperrt wurde. Grund hierfür ist eine zu hohe Heizleistung der Therme die von den Heizflächen nicht abgenommen werden kann. Das passiert, wenn eine Kombitherme in kleinen Wohnungen installiert werden, ohne die Heizleistung auf den Wärmebedarf der Wohnung einzustellen. Dann bleibt Euch nur die Brennersperrzeit abzuwarten oder die Therme einmal komplett aus zu schalten und wieder ein zu schalten. Damit stellt man die Brennersperrzeit zurück. Aber das ist nur ein Notbehelf. Ihr solltet bei der nächsten Wartung vom Wartungsmonteur die Heizleistung einstellen lassen, damit die Therme nicht ständig takten muß. Ein Nebeneffekt der zu hohen Heizleistung und dem daraus folgenden Takten, ist ein erhöhter Gasverbrauch.

I do not know the specialist terms used in the context of heating systems, but here is an attempt to explain it:

"Brennersperrzeit = burner locking time"

A heating system has a burner and this may be locked for some time due to technical reasons. During this locking time the burner does not work and you have to wait until this time is over. The locking time is a parameter which be can set by a technician. The purpose is to prevent damage from the heating system since it may happen that the generated heat cannot be given off fast enough by the heating elements in the rooms.

Answer (score 1):

I would translate *Brennersperrzeit* in English as

> burner cool-down delay

see [Collins: cool-down](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cool-down). An overheating condition was detected and the burner is now switched off so it can cool down to specified normal temperature range again.

Answer (score 0):

This is a compound noun. There are many of them in German, and most of them are not listed in any dictionaries, because our dictionaries would explode if you added every possible German compound noun.

Instead you have to cut it into its pieces, translate them and try to make sense of it:

- der **Brenner** = the burner
- **sperren** = to lock (die **Sperre** = the lock)
- die **Zeit** = the time

So, all together it gives **burner-lock-time** which I interpret as the time for which a burner is locked.

---

Other famous long German compound nouns:

- [Donaudampfschiffahrtsgesellschaft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donaudampfschiffahrtsgesellschaft)
- [Rindfleischetikettierungsüberwachungsaufgabenübertragungsgesetz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rinderkennzeichnungs-_und_Rindfleischetikettierungs%C3%BCberwachungsaufgaben%C3%BCbertragungsgesetz) (there is also a song about it on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Psq46MZjDYs))

Comment: Donaudampfschifffahrtsgesellschaft ist leider falsch geschrieben. Warum sollte man ein *f* weglassen? Weil es der Duden irgendwann so vorgab? Tut er übrigens nicht mehr.

Comment: @Olafant: Da wurde kein f weggelassen. Die Schreibweise mit 3 f wäre falsch, denn das ist ein Eigenname. Für Eigennamen gelten keine Rechtschreibregeln. Das ist so als würde man die [Schloßstraße](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schloßstraße_(Berlin-Steglitz)) in Berlin-Steglitz mit Doppel-S schreiben.

Answer (score 0):

Valliant, a well-known company for heating systems, mentions this in its [English instructions](http://file:///C:/Users/LENOVO%7E1/AppData/Local/Temp/0020261189_00_ENG.pdf) ([German insructions](http://file:///C:/Users/LENOVO%7E1/AppData/Local/Temp/0020261189_00.pdf)) as

> Burner anti-cycling time

[This website](https://myboiler.com/vaillant/vaillant-ecotec-boiler-anti-cycling-time/) explains the term as follows

> To prevent the boiler from switching on and off constantly in a short time, this function adds a time delay. This function is used only for heating mode and not hot water. It is an electronic function, which means after the timer is activated, the boiler will wait until this timer is finished, and then resume firing as normal. The timer will again be activated each and everytime the boiler needs to enter anti-cycling mode. This function is designed to prevent energy losses.